# JSON POST REQUEST USING AFNETWORKING XCODE

Tags: xcode5, http-post, afnetworking-2

I'm having a trouble and spend so many hours finding solution to my problem about posting a JSON data to our server. This is a x-www-form-urlencoded i think. When I use postman a google chrome plugin for testing GET and POST request it is working but when i applied it to my app. The server returns nothing and I think I have an error. This is what i post in postman.

```
access_token:myAccessToken
cartData:[{"mapAttributes":[{"name":"color","value":"Yellow","price":"0","id":"b_14","isSelected":1,"img_id":"1005"},{"name":"size","value":"Xl","price":"100","id":"b_11","isSelected":1,"img_id":"1005"},{"name":"material","value":"Metal","price":"0.00","id":"b_13","isSelected":1,"img_id":"1005"}],"quantity":"1","slug":"mi-3-16gb"}]
```

and the request is correct.
But when I applied it to my app.

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"access_token":token,@"cartData":myData};

     [manager POST:@"http://192.168.4.30/myUrl" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }]
```

The value of myData is:

```
[{"mapAttributes":[{"name":"color","value":"Yellow","price":"0","id":"b_14","isSelected":1,"img_id":"1005"},{"name":"size","value":"Xl","price":"100","id":"b_11","isSelected":1,"img_id":"1005"},{"name":"material","value":"Metal","price":"0.00","id":"b_13","isSelected":1,"img_id":"1005"}],"quantity":"1","slug":"mi-3-16gb"}]
```

it returns `()` and not having an error.

This is the return when I used postman.

```
{
    "6e2713a6efee97bacb63e52c54f0ada0": {
        "rowid": "6e2713a6efee97bacb63e52c54f0ada0",
        "productId": 557,
        "productItemId": 1515,
        "maximumAvailability": "2",
        "slug": "lg-optimus-g2-d802",
        "name": "LG Optimus G2 D802",
        "quantity": "1",
        "description": "<h1 id=\"prod_title\">LG Optimus G2 D802</h1>",
        "brand": "Custom",
        "originalPrice": "27690.0000",
        "finalPrice": "18829.2",
        "sellerDetails": {
            "sellerName": "lazada",
            "sellerRating": {
                "rateCount": 0,
                "rateDescription": {
                    "Item quality": 0,
                    "Communication": 0,
                    "Shipment time": 0
                }
            },
            "sellerContactNumber": "",
            "sellerEmail ": "ryanannatuvasquez2@easyshop.ph"
        },
        "images": {
            "1004": "./assets/product/557_128_20140715/557_128_20140715722500.jpg"
        },
        "mapAttributes": []
    }
}
```

please help me with my code. thankyou.

Comment: I don't know Objective C but is there any instance where the webservice returns nothing? E.g. if the access_token is invalid or something? I'd test by echoing a string in the webservice to first at least see if the webservice is being called properly.

Comment: When I tried it on postman the server returns nothing if I've enter a invalid format of JSON for example using {} rather than using [] for array of JSON. May Objective C is changing my JSON format I guess.

Comment: like in your webservice, if it were php, just put "die('TEST');" at the beginning and see if at least that is returned.  Then you might be able to diagnose the problem better.

Comment: I solved this one by making my BOOLEAN json as string. "true"... and restarting post man. :) Thank you sir Phil.

Answer (score 0):

Just change my JSON BOOLEAN data to string "true"

```
[{"mapAttributes":[{"name":"color","value":"Yellow","price":"0","id":"b_14","isSelected":"true","img_id":"1005"},{"name":"size","value":"Xl","price":"100","id":"b_11","isSelected":"true","img_id":"1005"},{"name":"material","value":"Metal","price":"0.00","id":"b_13","isSelected":"true","img_id":"1005"}],"quantity":"1","slug":"lg-optimus-g2-d802"}]
2014-10-14 11:56:11.833 Easyshop.ph[12399:1263983] [{"mapAttributes":[{"name":"color","value":"Yellow","price":"0","id":"b_14","isSelected":"true","img_id":"1005"},{"name":"size","value":"Xl","price":"100","id":"b_11","isSelected":"true","img_id":"1005"},{"name":"material","value":"Metal","price":"0.00","id":"b_13","isSelected":"true","img_id":"1005"}],"quantity":"1","slug":"lg-optimus-g2-d802"}]
```